# win 10 downgrade user accounts move issue

Tags: windows-10

Recently I upgrade my win 8.1 to win 10 and I don't like it. I really want to downgrade it back to win 8.1 I follow the instruction online: settings->Recovery->Go Back to Windows 8.1 and I met the error

'Before you go back to a previous version of windows, you'll need to put any user accounts you moved after your most recent upgrade back in their original location'

I am not sure how to fix it. Hope someone can help me with it thanks a lot.